How does DAC remap in STM32F103 (high density series) work?
May I remap the DAC output pins of my STM32F103ZET to another one? I saw this in the reference manual:

But cannot find anything about the pin outputs.

Datasheet makes it clear from the pin mapping that the two DAC outputs are always at pins PA4 and PA5.
They cannot be remapped.

I think it only remaps the DAC DMA, not the output pin.
/** TIM76_DAC_DMA remap to DMA1/DMA2 */
#define AFIO_MAPR2_TIM76_DAC_DMA_REMAPE         (1 << 11)

